# update query not working?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-room

I have the following Dao class:

```
@Dao
public interface AchievementDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertIntoDatabase(AchievementModel... achievementModel);

@Query("SELECT * FROM achievements WHERE game = :game")
AchievementModel[] getAchievementDataForGame(String game);

@Query("UPDATE achievements SET pointsAchieved = pointsAchieved + :points WHERE achievementKey = :achievementKey")
void updatePointsForKey(double points, String achievementKey);

@Query("SELECT * FROM achievements WHERE achievementKey LIKE :achievementKey")
AchievementModel getAchievementForKey(String achievementKey);
}
```

and the following model class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "achievements", indices = {@Index(value = {"achievementKey"}, unique = true)})
public class AchievementModel {

@PrimaryKey @NonNull
private String achievementKey;
private String title;
private String description;
private double pointsAchieved;
private int imageId;
private int viewType;
private String game;

public AchievementModel(@NonNull String achievementKey, String title, String description,
                        double pointsAchieved, int imageId, int viewType, String game) {
    this.achievementKey = achievementKey;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.pointsAchieved = pointsAchieved;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.viewType = viewType;
    this.game = game;
}

@NonNull
public String getAchievementKey() {
    return achievementKey;
}

public void setAchievementKey(@NonNull String achievementKey) {
    this.achievementKey = achievementKey;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public double getPointsAchieved() {
    return pointsAchieved;
}

public void setPointsAchieved(double pointsAchieved) {
    this.pointsAchieved = pointsAchieved;
}

public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

public int getViewType() {
    return viewType;
}

public void setViewType(int viewType) {
    this.viewType = viewType;
}

public String getGame() {
    return game;
}

public void setGame(String game) {
    this.game = game;
}
}
```

The first 2 queries in the DAO class are working absolutely fine whereas the last 2 queries updatePointsForKey and getAchievementForKey are not working. They are being called correctly from a background thread. Please help. Do tell me if more information is required about the question.

Comment: For the second one you forgot the [] (because it's a select). The first one maybe you should try @Query("UPDATE achievements SET pointsAchieved += :points WHERE achievementKey = :achievementKey")

Comment: Hey @Ko2r! Thank you so much for the fix of the second query it's working now. Whereas the solution for the first query didn't work. It's giving a lint error

Answer (score 0):

The update query maybe returns an int instead of void ... What do you think ?

Comment: Still not working. I think it's suppose to return the the updated row number but it's just returning 0. And the database is not updating.

Comment: If you just try to update without adding, it's changing something ? Just to identify if the + is the issue or if it could be the ID ...

Comment: It gives the same result when I just try to update without adding i.e. db is not updated. whereas when I run the following code `"UPDATE achievements SET pointsAchieved = pointsAchieved + 1.0 WHERE achievementKey = \"some_string\""` it's working absolutely fine. Don't know why. My arguments are being correctly passed.

Comment: So it means that the issue is on the Key ... have you tried `like` instead of `=` ?

Comment: hey ko2r! thank you so much for your support. It's working now. The problem was with the arguments being passed indeed. The query was correct. So sorry for the trouble caused.